# How to run functions in other tab controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

So i have a tab bar navigation controller, my application loads with the first controller selected my question is how can i run a function in other controllers even without selecting them.

The prolem is each tab view is embeded in a navgation controller, and im getting an error when i call the function from the first view controller :

```
[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] myfunction];
```

[UINavigationController myfunction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d83ff0

Answer (score 0):

Controller is an object. You can send a message to the object. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a reference to that controller. When a tabbarcontroller is setup it's given tabs and controllers (if that wasn't obvious) and these are stored in properties. So getting a reference is basically this snippet:

```
UIViewController *viewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[indexOfViewController];
```

From there you should be able to call methods like any other object in objective c

```
[viewController methodName];
```

as long as the method declaration exist with in the .h file then you should be fine.

[UITabBarController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: ah, okay, then i would be correct in assuming you made sure that the viewControllers array is not nil, and correct in assuming you have the proper index for the controller?

Comment: then i'm stumped :D i'd have to look at the code base

Comment: although that error you are getting means you are calling a function on the wrong object, in your scenario on a UINavigationController object instead of your UIViewController Subclass object

Answer (score 0):

found my way , had to do this

[[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] firstObject] myfunction];

Comment: oh, yes [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] is a UINavigationController which has a viewControllers array, to which you want the first one :3 . All of my comments are not needed anymore XD